# Why is the validator reporting a JSON error?

Tags: json

In a JSON file like below I put a list of commands that I will need in my application. For an unknown reason, the validator returns me an error.

```
{
    "CommandsAT": ["ABORT 'BUSY'", 
                          "ABORT 'NO CARRIER'",
                          "ABORT 'VOICE'",
                          "ABORT 'NO DIALTONE'",
                          "ABORT 'NO DIAL TONE'",
                          "ABORT 'NO ANSWER'",
                          "ABORT 'DELAYED'",
                          "REPORT CONNECT",
                          "TIMEOUT 6",
                          "' 'ATQ0'",
                          "'OK-AT-OK' 'ATZ'",
                          "TIMEOUT 3",
                          "'OK\d-AT-OK' 'ATI'",
                          "'OK' 'ATZ'",
                          "'OK' 'AT+FLO=0'",
                          "'OK' 'ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0'",
                          "'OK' @/etc/ppp/chatscripts/mode",
                          "'OK-AT-OK' 'AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"my_apn.pl\"'",
                          "'OK' 'ATDT*99#'",
                          "TIMEOUT 30",
                          "CONNECT ''"
                          ]
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error on line 13:
...TIMEOUT 3",                        "'OK\d-AT-OK' 'ATI'"
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Am I making a syntax error?

Comment: I think it has a problem with the `\d`.

Comment: You're right I was able to confirm this when I deleted line "'OK\d-AT-OK' 'ATI'",. How could I make it treat it like text?

Comment: `\d` is equal to `d`

Comment: command 'OK\d-AT-OK' 'ATI' will be send later like string to modem device. I cant change "\d" to "d". Is there any way for json to ignore "\d" and treat it as a normal string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another `\` before the problematic one, so now you have `\\`; the first cancels the "escape-ness" of the second, so you're left with just the `\` character.

Answer (score -1):

The error isn't cause in line 13 is caused in line 14. The problem is the `\` symbol. I've fixed your issue:

```
  {
    "CommandsAT": ["ABORT 'BUSY'", 
                          "ABORT 'NO CARRIER'",
                          "ABORT 'VOICE'",
                          "ABORT 'NO DIALTONE'",
                          "ABORT 'NO DIAL TONE'",
                          "ABORT 'NO ANSWER'",
                          "ABORT 'DELAYED'",
                          "REPORT CONNECT",
                          "TIMEOUT 6",
                          "' 'ATQ0'",
                          "'OK-AT-OK' 'ATZ'",
                          "TIMEOUT 3",
                          "'OK\"d\"-AT-OK' 'ATI'",
                          "'OK' 'ATZ'",
                          "'OK' 'AT+FLO=0'",
                          "'OK' 'ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0'",
                          "'OK' @/etc/ppp/chatscripts/mode",
                          "'OK-AT-OK' 'AT+CGDCONT=1,\"IP\",\"my_apn.pl\"'",
                          "'OK' 'ATDT*99#'",
                          "TIMEOUT 30",
                          "CONNECT ''"
                          ]
}
```

Comment: With your solution I got 'OK"d"-AT-OK' 'ATI', but I need 'OK\d-AT-OK' 'ATI'